# Return text from URL in GTM Custom JS variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I need to capture text from the file saved under URL (ex. https://fiddle.jshell.net/robots.txt) And return it under the function.

What is on my mind:

```
function(){
var url = 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/robots.txt'
var storedText;

fetch(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    response.text().then(function(text) {
      storedText = text;
      done();
    });
  });
function done() {
  return storedText;
}
});
```

Unfortunately this function is not working. I received an error: *Error at line 2, character 2: Parse error. primary expression expected Type: JavaScript compiler error*

This should be used as a Custom JavasSript Variable in Google Tag Manager

Also this [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) is not explaining my issue and all solutions were checked by me, nothing worked due Parse error or console error.

I have to use GTM custom JavaScrip Variable, I can use anything else. 
Simpler JS than better.

Answer (score 0):

Function done() returns storedText value to a point of call, i. e. it works but returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using an external call within a custom Custom JavasSript Variable in GTM:

You can not really control how often a Custom JavasSript Variable is executed in GTM. An it is executed a lot.
Just do the test and run a console log from a custom javascript variable.